# Why don't we add parenthesis when writing comparator in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, lambda, comparator

Here is a code explaining what I mean.

```cpp
static bool comparator(int a, int b) {
    if(a > b) return false;
    return true;
}

sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comparator); // why don't we write comparator()
```

Comment: Because that way we would have called it once and passed the result of that call to the `sort` as a comparator function, instead of passing a pointer to the `comparator` and then calling to it in process of sorting.

Comment: Because we are not passing the result of calling that function but instead a pointer to that function.

Comment: Note that if `comparator` were a function object *type* (`struct` with `operator()` member function), we would write `comparator()` to construct such an object. This is also a common pattern.

Comment: `comparator()` would **invoke** the function, and pass the returned result to the `sort` as a parameter.  But that's not was `sort` needs for that parameter, it needs a comparison function or lambda.  (And to **invoke** the function, it'd need to have arguments for both parameters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why don't we add parenthesis when writing `comparator` in c++?

Because we're not passing the result of calling that function but instead a pointer to that function. In particular, the third argument named `comparator` to `std::sort` will **implicitly decay** to a *pointer to that function type* due to **type decay**. You might already be familiar with type decay for built in arrays which also automatically decay to a pointer to their first element. This(a free function to function pointer) is just another instance of type decay.

If we were to pass `comaparator()` then we would be passing a value of type `bool` which is not what is expected. Additionally since `comparator` takes 2 `int` arguments and so if we'were to write `comparator()` it would be invalid because we're not passing any argument to it.

It is **as if you wrote**:

```
//---------------------------v--------------->note the & operator used here which is optional
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), &comparator);   //this statement is equivalent to the statement that you have in your question
```

The above modified statement is equivalent to the statement that you have in your example. The only *syntactic difference* here is that here we have **explicitly** used the `&` to indicate that we're passing a pointer to the function named `comparator`.

Comment: Like an C-style array decays to a pointer a function name decays to a function pointer.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes i am fully aware of that. Was there a reason you mentioned the same?

Comment: That wasn't directed at you but to give abhi5heklal something to compare it to.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Ok. IMO tagging them using `@`  would have been more clear or posting the same in the comment section of the original question would be even better.

Comment: Didn't feel right in the original question since *type decay* was only brought up here.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Comments under a post seem to suggest there is something wrong with the post. So that's why i am concerned. Tagging the user/OP would've been clear.

Comment: and I do think the answer would be better by making the comparison to how arrays decay the same way.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I have added that this is similar to c-array arrays decaying to pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 2):

If you will write

```
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comparator());
```

then it means that the argument expression of the function `std::sort` `comparator()` must be evaluated. But neither arguments are supplied to the function call `comparator()`. So the compiler will issue an error message.

On the other hand, if you will write

```
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), comparator);
```

then the function designator `comparator` is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function and the function `std::sort` within itself will call the function using the pointer and supplying two arguments to it.

Comment: Actually `std::sort` is a template function, so it has extra flexibility. It can take either a function or a functor object that implements `operator()`.