# why greater<int> needs following "()" when used as comparator in sorting?

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, compare, comparator

code1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct man {
  int age;
  int h, w;
};

struct compare {
  bool operator()(const man &m1, const man &m2) { return m1.age < m2.age; }
};

priority_queue<man, vector<man>, compare> mq;

int main() {
  man tmp;
  tmp.age = 40;
  mq.push(tmp);

  tmp.age = 50;
  mq.push(tmp);

  tmp.age = 30;
  mq.push(tmp);

  tmp.age = 1;
  mq.push(tmp);

  while (!mq.empty()) {
    cout << mq.top().age << " ";
    mq.pop();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

code2

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0};
  int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

  sort(arr, arr + n, greater<int>());

  cout << "Array after sorting : \n";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

Both two codes above are "fine".
My question is about "compare" and "greater<int>()".
"compare" is a struct. "greater<int>" is also a struct.
Then why "()" is not needed after "compare" but is needed after "greater<int>"?

According to
https://cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/
, greater is a struct as shown below.

```
template <class T> struct greater {
    bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x>y;}
    typedef T first_argument_type;
    typedef T second_argument_type;
    typedef bool result_type;
};
```

Comment: Same difference than type `int` and value `int{}` (`0`)... You have `std::vector<int>` (and not `std::vector<int{}>`).

Comment: Because the template argument must be a type, and the function argument must be a value.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046760/syntax-for-using-stdgreater-when-calling-stdsort-in-c), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72451130/why-dont-we-add-parenthesis-when-writing-comparator-in-c), [Dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005801/whats-the-difference-in-comparator-syntax-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`std::greater<int>` is a *type*.

`std::greater<int>()` is an *instance* of the type, an object.

The [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function needs a callable *object*, not a type, as function argument in the call.

For [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) you pass the *type* as a template argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between *types* and *objects*.

`sort` is a function call, and so needs to have an object passed as the third argument. `greater<int>()` creates a `greater<int>` object.

But `priority_queue<man, vector<man>, compare> mq;` is a declaration, so `priority_queue<man, vector<man>, compare>` is a (template) type, and just needs the type `compare` as a template argument.

To make a simpler example consider

```
compare c = compare();
```

The first `compare` is the type of the variable `c`, the second `compare` creates the object that will be the value of `c`.